# How Do I Iterate Generic List Using For Each Type For Loop

Tags: java, collections, foreach, generic-list

I have been given an assignment to create a list of lists where I should be able to iterate through the lists using the 'for each' type of 'for' loop, versus building a constructor for Iterator. The problem is that when I the code below, I get the error msg "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable". Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GList<InnerList> list = new GList<InnerList>(); 
    GList<InnerList> numList = new GList<InnerList>();
    InnerList lst = new InnerList ();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer;      
    while (true){
        System.out.println ("Do you want to create a list (y/n)? ");
        answer = sc.next();
        if (answer.equals("y")){
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the list: ");
            answer = sc.next();
            lst.setName(answer);
            if (list.isEmpty()== true){
                list.insertFirstItem(lst);
            }
            else {
                list.insertNext(lst);
            }           
        }               
        while (true){
            System.out.println("Do you want to enter a number (y/n)?");
            answer = sc.next();
            if (answer.equals("y")){
                System.out.println("Enter Number: ");
                answer = sc.next();
                try {
                    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(answer);
                    lst.setInner(num1);
                    if (list.isEmpty() == true){
                        list.insertFirstItem(lst);  
                    }
                    else {
                        list.insertNext(lst);
                    }                       
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    System.out.println("You must enter an number! " + e);
                    sc.close();
                }                       
            }
            return;
        }       
    }
    for (GList<InnerList> ilName : list){ //here are my error msgs. I also tried replacing GList<InnerList> with 'InnerList' and String. 
        for(GList<InnerList> ilInts : list){
            System.out.println(ilName);
            System.out.println(ilInts);
        }
    }       
}
```

Can someone help me understand why GList is not considered an instance of java.lang.iterable when collections should be iterable?

Thank you.

Comment: What error is it showing??

Comment: The error in the original post is ""Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not considered as an instance of `java.lang.Iterable` because it does not implement the interface `java.lang.Iterable`. As simple as that. Change its declaration to

```
public class GList<T> implements Iterable<T>
```

and you'll be ale to use the foreach loop with it. But since `list` is an instance of `GList<InnerList>`, and since a `GList<InnerList>` contains instances of `InnerList` (at least, I guess so), the loop should be:

```
for (InnerList innerList : list) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You are correct, it does contain instance of InnerList. When I add 'implements Iterable<T>' to the GList<T> class, it tells me "The type GList<T> must implement the inherited abstract method Iterable<T>.iterator()"; what does that mean?

Comment: That you must implement the method declared in the Iterable interface: `public Iterator<T> iterator()`. Do you understand the concept of interfaces? If so, you should understand that every method declared in an interface that you implement must be implemented. If not, read a good introductory Java book, or [the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

Comment: I understand the concept of interfaces but we've been given the "only" public methods we are allowed to use and public Iterator<T> is not one of them?

Comment: If GList doesn't implement Iterable, you can't use the foreach loop to iterate them. There's no workaround. So ask your teacher what he actually wants.

Comment: I have a public boolean hasNext(T head) method? I can add the rest if it would be best...

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer but your comment about asking him got to look back in my notes. He's looking for us to do something like this:   while (list.hasNext()){
   System.out.println(list.getNextItem());
  }
  break;

Comment: Thank you for your help JB Nizet! If there's one thing I've learned from this project, it's that if I'm adding classes that he didn't list, then I'm thinking in a different box then the instructor wants us to. -Cheers

Answer (score -2):

It is a syntax error and the coorect syntax would be ,

```
for(InnerList ilName : GList) {
   for(InnerList ilInts : GList) {
     System.out.println(ilName);
     System.out.println(ilInts);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is actually wrong. This is not the correct way to use Enhanced For.